# Can't set headers after they are sent error happens with socket.io

Tags: node.js, sockets

I am writing a very simple nodejs socket.io app. Somehow this returns "can't set headers after they are sent" error. but I can't see the point where the header is set again. I've only called server.listen once and I believe socket.listen works independently so it shouldn't conflict.

I am aware that can't set headers error had been posted a multiple times. I've read them briefly and I also understand how does response.writeHead works under normal circumstances(I've experimented with some node.js apps with response.writeHead, they worked fine most cases) it seems I am missing something from here. is it due to socket.io?

```
const fs = require("fs");

const server = require("http").createServer();
const io = require("socket.io").listen(server);

server.listen(52273,function(){
  console.log("server up");
});

server.on("request",function(request,response){
  fs.readFile("mainpage.html",function(error,data){
    response.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":"text/html"});
    response.end(data);
  });
});

io.sockets.on("connection",function(socket){

  var roomName = null;
  socket.on("join", function(data){
    roomName = data;
    socket.join(data);
    console.log("client joined" + data);
  });

  socket.on("message",function(data){
    io.sockets.in(roomName).emit("message","test");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It probably helps a bit here to understand a little bit about how socket.io works with your web server.  socket.io uses the webSocket protocol as it's base protocol.  A webSocket connection starts with an HTTP request that has special header set in it to indicate the start of a webSocket connection.  A properly functioning web server will see this webSocket header and turn the request over to the webSocket handler to initiate the webSocket connection.

But, this handler you have:

```
server.on("request",function(request,response){
  fs.readFile("mainpage.html",function(error,data){
    response.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":"text/html"});
    response.end(data);
  });
});
```

Looks like it is responding to every single request that arrives and sending a response, no matter what the request was.  So, I can imagine that when the webSocket request comes in you're sending two responses, one from the webSocket server code and one from your `request` handler above.

Probably, you need to be able to only send your `mainpage.html` response for particular URLs that are not your webSocket request.

To see a little more about what's going in, insert a `console.log()` into here:

```
server.on("request",function(request,response){
  console.log(request.url);
  fs.readFile("mainpage.html",function(error,data){
    response.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":"text/html"});
    response.end(data);
  });
});
```

And, you will probably see you are sending your mainpage.html to a webSocket request which is not what you want to do.  You will likely want to add some `if` logic so that your request handler is avoiding the webSocket requests.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. but last time the error was found on the closing parenthesis(}) of fs.readfile() method. The page initially loads fine(which means it is working properly after webSocket request) then just crashes. I think I should try using different version of node.js and socket.io. I'll be back with the result.

Comment: @SungryeolPark - Yes, that is EXACTLY where the error would be if the problem is as I've described.  Your webSocket handler has ALREADY sent the response for the incoming webSocket connection, but your generic request handler is trying to send ANOTHER response and that is not allowed.  Poking around with different versions of socket.io is not the issue here.  Your code is broken.  You need to only send `mainpage.html` when a specific URL is requested, not when ANY request comes in because you are trying to send `mainpage.html` even when webSocket requests come in and that is wrong.

Comment: @SungryeolPark - Put the `console.log(request.url)` into your request handler, identify what URL shows there when the webSocket connects and then add an `if` statement to NOT send any response when it's the webSocket URL.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Node you using?

We had the same problem when we were using 0.9.x. I downgraded Node to 0.8.4 and the problem seems to have gone away.

My best guess is something in Node has changed that Socket.io doesnt agree with.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'll try downgrade my node

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. I've solved problem by installing express to my experiment app. I've read the manual again and discovered the socket.io v2 is now requiring express app as a dependency. It seems I have been using socket.io v2 but somehow sticked to socket.io v1 style app writing. It also worked when I downgraded it to socket.io v1.

TL;DR - socket.io v2 is not compatible with apps written for socket.io v1. When a socket.io app returns "can't set headers after they are sent" errors, try use proper version of the socket.io or install correct dependencies.